# C Token Parsing

Tags: c, parsing, tokenize

So I'm trying to implement a token parser that doesn't use any C library functions like strtok() etc but I'm having a few issues with access violations and after reading several similar questions on here still haven't got it nailed down. Anyone willing to offer some pointers?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int maxTokens = 10;
    char* tokens[10];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < maxTokens; i++)
    {
        tokens[i] = NULL;
    }

    char* str = "This,is,a,test,string";

    int result = parseLine(str, ',', tokens, maxTokens);

    printf("%d tokens were found!", result);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int parseLine(char* str, char delimeter, char* tokens[], int maxTokens)
{
    char* srcStr = str;

    int strlen = 0;
    int tokenCount = 0;

    if(srcStr[strlen] != delimeter && srcStr[strlen] != '\0')
    {
        tokens[tokenCount] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen+1);
        tokens[tokenCount] = &srcStr[strlen];
        tokenCount++;
    }

    while(srcStr[strlen] != '\0')
    {
        if(srcStr[strlen] == delimeter)
        {
            tokens[tokenCount-1][strlen] = '\0';
            if(srcStr[strlen+1] != '\0')
            {
                tokens[tokenCount] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen+1);
                tokens[tokenCount] = &srcStr[++strlen];
                tokenCount++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strlen++;
        }
    }

    return tokenCount;
}
```

Comment: You might want to change the variable name "strlen". Even if you're not using the `string.h` functions, using that name will make your code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)
The hard way:

```
char* tokens[10];

int i;
for(i = 0; i < maxTokens; i++)
{
    tokens[i] = NULL;
}
```

The easy way:

```
char tokens[10] = { NULL };
```

2) This line won't copy a string ( it will just create another reference to it )

```
char* srcStr = str;
```

this will:

```
char* srcStr = (char*) malloc ( strlen(str) + 1 );
strcpy( srcStr , str );
```

3) Don't reinvent the wheel EXCEPT if you really have to. I have learned this the hard way. Believe me. You have made tons of mistakes in your function. If you really want to do this for "educational" purposes or something else, get some information on pointers and strings first

Comment: I agree he can implement whatever he wants to. We all do. That's why I told him to get some more info on pointers and strings. However, I think it is important he understands that there is a reason these functions exist already.

Comment: I removed my down vote because you fixed this post. It's likely academic reasons based on his simplified implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that, not sure why I didn't see the shallow copy :S

Answer (score 2):

"Anyone willing to offer some pointers?"

[image: Every computer, at the unreachable memory address 0x-1, stores a secret. I found it, and it is that all humans ar-- SEGMENTATION FAULT.]

In all seriousness, though, consider using a debugger (I recommend Visual Studio if you're using Windows), or Valgrind (Linux only) to catch access violations.

Even without reading your code at all, I was able to get useful information about the line number where the segfault occurs:

```
==8272== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8272== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8272== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8272== Command: ./a.out
==8272== 
==8272== 
==8272== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8272==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x400868
==8272==    at 0x40069E: parseLine (asdf.c:22)
==8272==    by 0x400790: main (asdf.c:52)
==8272== 
==8272== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8272==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==8272==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 1 bytes allocated
==8272== 
==8272== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8272==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==8272==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8272==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8272==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8272==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8272== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8272== 
==8272== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8272== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Segmentation fault
```

In your code, this corresponds to the line `tokens[tokenCount-1][strlen] = '\0';`.

Comment: Haha I was waiting for a comment about that xD Yeah I'm using the VS Debugger.